# Laravel database seeding

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use the database seeder feature. But its not inserting the row, nor even showing any error.. I need suggestion please. Laravel version 5.2.29
[image]

Comment: show me your database seeder.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `DatabaseSeeder` isn't calling `UserstableSeeder`. Try putting something like this into your `DatabaseSeeder`:

```
$this->call(UserstableSeeder::class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
php artisan db:seed --class= UserstableSeeder
```

Moreover whenever you create a new seeder file don't forget to run

```
composer dump-autoload
```